# using android pagination library with items in Memory

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

i try to implement the pagination library , using rxJava , first of all , i call the NetworkApi to load the full data , then i want to use the pagiantion with the full loaded data,  how can i do it with the library  , i am trying to use the ItemKeyedDataSource Class , but please , do i need always to pass the element size to my api call or i can work only with the in memory loaded data ?

this is my api call :

```
  public fun getMembersPagination(): MutableLiveData<ResultContainer<PagedList<MembersModel.Data.Member?>>> {
    disposable = client.getMembersPaged()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retry(0)
            .subscribe(
                    { result ->
                        onRetrieveUserData(result)
                    },
                    { error -> onRetrieveUserDataError(error) }
            )

    return pagedList
}
```

i don't treat the pagiantion from my Api

this is the api :

```
  @GET("members")
fun getMembersPaged(): Observable<PagedList<MembersModel.Data.Member?>>
```

ItemKeyedDataSource  code :

```
    class MembersPaginationDataSource(private val memberId: Int)
: ItemKeyedDataSource<Int, MembersModel.Data.Member?>() {

val client by lazy {
    RetrofitClient.RetrofitClient()
}

var disposable: Disposable? = null

private var allMembers = MutableLiveData<PagedList<MembersModel.Data.Member?>>()


override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<MembersModel.Data.Member?>) {

    getMembersPagination().observe()


}

override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<MembersModel.Data.Member?>) {
}

override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<MembersModel.Data.Member?>) {


}

override fun getKey(item: MembersModel.Data.Member): Int = item.id!!


public fun getMembersPagination(): MutableLiveData<PagedList<MembersModel.Data.Member?>> {
    disposable = client.getMembersPaged()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retry(0)
            .subscribe(
                    { result ->
                        onRetrieveUserData(result)
                    },
                    { error -> onRetrieveUserDataError(error) }
            )

    return allMembers
}


private fun onRetrieveUserData(membersModel: PagedList<MembersModel.Data.Member?>?) {
    allMembers.postValue(membersModel)
}

private fun onRetrieveUserDataError(error: Throwable) {
    allMembers.postValue(null)
}
```

}

i stop at that point

Comment: whats your custom `ItemKeyedDataSource` implementation? and why do you want to mix it with rx?

Comment: i make my api call with RxJava , i want to load all my items at once in Memory and the use the pagination

Comment: why do you make your api calls with rx? whats your custom `ItemKeyedDataSource` implementation? did you see [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample) for example?

Comment: i add the code at the top

Comment: in google exemple they handle the pagination from the server , but i am asking if i can use the pagination from the client side ?

Comment: did you check in what thread `loadInitial`, `loadAfter` and `loadBefore` are executed on?

Comment: You can implement from client side also. But first ask few questions to your self 1. Is app going to have too many items in local database that requires pagination? 2. Its ok for api call to take too long time to fetch data (Because server does not support pagination or whatever reason you have).

Comment: i want to make the pagination without saving the data into my database , like the pagination in the ios UITableView

Comment: @pskink the problem is that every exemple  use the pageNumber or the PageSize to call the api

Comment: and your API returns the whole dataset in one huge chunk or what? if so, how bit it is?

Comment: @pskink 152 elements

Comment: @chandil03 i want to load the data at once about 152 records and then use the pagination with the list only

Comment: so why do you want a pagination at all if you keep all the data in memory? why not to pass it to your adapter directly without any pagination?

Comment: i am afraid that the recycleView will have some problem when the data get bigger

Comment: no, it does not have

Comment: so if i wanna work with pagination libray i should either save the data into Room Database or pass the page or size into my api to get the specific chunk of data ?

Comment: yes, doesnt your api require any ids or page numbers?

Comment: no , i fetch the data at once

Comment: @pskink is right. There is no need of pagination if you are fetching data at once.  There wont be any problem with recycler view. But you will hold too much RAM that is not required. Better option is you save it in database and implement pagination and clear database when you re-fetch data again.

Comment: ok those 152 items, how big they are in bytes (xml or json response size)?

Comment: the body size is almost 100KB

Comment: 100KB? a small image 200x200 pixels takes more memory... so you dont have to worry about any pagination in your adapter